# How can we float divs with scroll bar

Tags: css-float

There are   two div on the right and on the left.How can I float right div with the vertical scroll bar can you write an example Please help : (

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Usually it's best practice to provide some sort of example of what you've tried. Just saying "please give me code" is kind of frowned upon. We want to be here when you get stuck, not when you want other people to do your work for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, divs are floating in this example:
You can do it by applying this css:

```
 position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    right:0;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hatefull/XQrpD/)

Comment: No I don't want like this, I want just like facebook. One floating div will be under header div and it will slip down it's top height decreases :( sorry my english is so bad I hope I can explain my self :(

Comment: If i understood you correctly, then you need to set a fixed position to header too, and they will all float